# Reduce Object array with same values

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, reduce, higher-order-functions

I have an array of Javascript Objects, which contain two important values `date` and `status`

I want to reduce them into an array of unique dates, where all the values are parsed into an object, that contains each of the status and the date.

I have tried using the reduce funtion, but i can't seem to collect the `date`s properly, so that all the data is collected properly.

The unique statuses are: `"System Labelled", "Discarded", "Saved", "Reviewed"`

So for example:

```
[{status: "System Labelled", date: Thu Mar 05 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)},
{status: "System Labelled", date: Thu Mar 05 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)},
{status: "System Labelled", date: Thu Mar 05 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)},
{status: "Discarded", date: Tue Mar 10 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)},
{status: "Saved", date: Sat Jan 11 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)}] 
---->
[{System Labelled: 1, Discarded: 0, Saved: 0, Reviwed: 0, date: Thu Mar 05 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)}, 
{System Labelled: 2, Discarded: 0, Saved: 0, Reviwed: 0, date:  Sun Apr 05 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)}, 
{System Labelled: 0, Discarded: 1, Saved: 0, Reviwed: 0, date:  Tue Mar 10 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)}, 
{System Labelled: 0, Discarded: 0, Saved: 1, Reviwed: 0, date:  Sat Jan 11 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)},
```

Here is the code i have so far:

```
const objects= [{status: "System Labelled", date: new Date("19-03-2020")},
{status: "System Labelled", date: new Date("19-03-2020")},
{status: "Discarded", date:  new Date("19-03-2020")},
{status: "Saved", date:  new Date("19-03-2020")}]

objects.reduce((acc, curr) =>{
  console.log(acc.includes(curr.status))
  if(acc.includes(curr.status)){
    curr[acc.status]++
  }
},[])
```

Comment: please add the code.

Comment: @NinaScholz What code I'm sorry?

Comment: the code you tried.

Comment: Answer is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take an object for grouping and get the values as result array.

You need valid dates for it.

```js
const
    statuses = ["System Labelled", "Discarded", "Saved", "Reviewed"],
    objects = [{ status: "System Labelled", date: "2020-03-19" }, { status: "System Labelled", date: "2020-03-19" }, { status: "Discarded", date: "2020-03-19" }, { status: "Saved", date: "2020-03-19" }],
    result = Object.values(objects.reduce((acc, { status, date }) => {
        acc[date] = acc[date] || { date, ...Object.fromEntries(statuses.map(k => [k, 0])) };
        acc[date][status]++;
        return acc;
    }, {}));

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It seems to me that the OP has date objects, not strings so not sure `acc[date]` etc. is going to work.

Comment: ít works with a date instance `new Date("2020-03-19")` as well, because `Date` returns a string as key for the object, like `"Thu Mar 19 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"` (german location) and takes as `date` propery an iso string `"2020-03-19T00:00:00.000Z"`. (which is strange).

Comment: I think ISO string is from SO console. If "2020-03-19" is replaced with `new Date("2020-03-19")` in the source objects, the *result* object values are date strings, not date objects. Just s minor quibble. :-)

Answer (score -1):

what if you get the timestamp of each date and then add it as a string after the status it has to create one single string.

**Example Object**

[{status: "System Labelled", date: Thu Mar 05 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)}

**Would Be**

"System Labelled 1583366400"

And then you could just substring the timestamp to convert it to a date again

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better what do you expect to be done?